# How can I create a local Active Directory programatically using c#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Problem: our tests are now failing locally because we migrated to Azure AD. We cannot be domain joined to a local AD, while being joined to an Azure AD. Now our tests fail on our local development machines because our machines are not part of a domain.

I am thinking of maybe creating a local directory programmatically before each test being ran. Is this even possible given what I've described? I am using C#. I couldn't find much information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory is a windows server inbuilt role and it cannot be created programmatically. You can join your devices to both Azure AD and on-premises Active Directory - Hybrid Azure AD join. Check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join-hybrid#:%7E:text=If%20your%20environment%20has%20an,with%20your%20Azure%20Active%20Directory.) to get more detailed information